# Why does Monero use epee in the crypto module?

Tags: cryptonote, cryptonight

Is there any obvious gain to using epee in the crypto module?

I don't know why this code is inside crypto instead of cryptonote:

```
  inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const crypto::public_key &v) {
    epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
  }
  inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const crypto::secret_key &v) {
    epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
  }
  inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const crypto::key_derivation &v) {
    epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
  }
  inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const crypto::key_image &v) {
    epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
  }
  inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const crypto::signature &v) {
    epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
  }
```

It is a way to convert data to hex, so why is this part of the crypto module?

And maybe a template function can do the job:

```
template <typename T> std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, T &v) {
  epee::to_hex::formatted(o, epee::as_byte_span(v)); return o;
}
```

As we know public_key and private_key are parts of cryptonote not crypto. So why should this code be put into the crypto module?

To my understanding, the crypto module only cares about hashing. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It may help to first understand that CryptoNote is a *protocol* and that the crypto module contains *cryptographic primitives*.

`public_key, secret_key, key_derivation, key_image, signature`... these are all cryptographic primitives, hence they are all correctly in the crypto module, as are the hashing functions.

The reason for the output stream functions being in the crypto module and not CryptoNote is that they are not CryptoNote specific. They provide a way to output the primitives to a stream (encoded as hex).

Comment: But as far as I know public/private keys are used for wallet address , transaction encryption, blockchain recording and validation not for generating hash. Only the hash is what related to crypto module the most where pow algorithm is the core for this module. I think keys would better be hold inside cryptonote core where transactions are generated. It seems the consistency is broken when putting keys into crypto module.

Comment: No, the crypto module holds much more than just hashing functions - it holds all the cryptographic primitives. For example, all the ECC math is in [this file](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c). Again, CryptoNote is a protocol, crypto holds cryptographic primitives (which are used in many places).

Comment: As what you've addressed, I think account.cpp should be moved to crypto module, where it use public keys and encryption to generate new keys. Both keys and encryption are used.

Comment: "Account" is not a cryptographic primitive. Just because something "uses" a cryptographic primitive, does not make it one.

Comment: so is it a must to introduce epee just for formatting strings?

Comment: No it is not "a must" to add there. It makes _sense_ to add there. It is not used to format a string, it used to write the type to an output stream as a hex encoded string.

Comment: so why not put that in the stream module?

Comment: Because epee is a general purpose library that you wouldn't want to add specializations to like this. It's designed to be used by other modules/classes.

Comment: I mean stream functions.  As we can find [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/serialization/crypto.h)

Comment: Those are not stream functions. They are for serialization.

Comment: Are they serialized through streams?

Comment: The serialization code is for network / storage. The stream functions in the crypto module, as I recall, is just used for logging / display.

Comment: But both of them are streamed:)

Comment: And your point?